# enum vs Interface design

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a design problem where the requirement is something like this :

1. Write a generate function that takes a parameter("TYPE")
2. Depending on the TYPE, I need to generate a String and return it. So TYPE effectively changes the way you generate the String.

I am deliberating between two design options :

1. Using enum  : Create a enum having the TYPES. Then provide a generate method that depending on TYPE does the processing and returns a string.
2. Using Interface : Create an interface having a function generate(). Create implementations for each TYPE, to implement the generate().

Which do you feel is better and for what reasons.

Comment: Do both: create an enum that implements an interface with a `generate()` method. Then you have the best of both worlds.

Comment: Yeah sounds good. But what advantage does enum provide with respect to class implementing interface

Comment: Sounds a bit like you dumped your homework here. What are **your** thoughts?

Comment: Sorry if it appeared so, but homework doesn't give you solutions to choose from. I came up with these two solutions with a thought that the first one being simple and sufficient enough if the TYPES don't change much. And the second one good in scenarios where the TYPES might change so that we count on scalability. I posted to see if people can see any other benefits

Answer (score 1):

Although, Approach # 2, follows the **Open/Closed Principle** of OOAD i.e You will be adding new interface implementation, everytime new TYPE is added and you will not modify existing code, which is very safe approach as it does not need testing of old code/method. So your code will be open for extension but closed for modification. However, if you are going to very frequently add new TYPE, then Approach # 2, makes sense.

IMO, in this case, I would suggest to use Approach # 1, as the business requirement is really simple i.e to generate a String based on Parameter TYPE. So using interface will be over-engineering in my opinion(if TYPES are not going to be added frequently).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It will be good to use some design pattern for this problem statement to make your code more robust and reusable. I will suggest to you Strategy Design Pattern. It is abstraction based pattern that uses Interface.

Basic Example:

```
public interface IMyStrategy
{
    string Generate(string someValue);
}

public class StragegyA : IMyStrategy
{
    public string Generate(string somevalue)
    {
        return /Implementation/;
    }
}

public class StragegyB : IMyStrategy
{
    public string Generate(string somevalue)
    {
        return /Implementation/;
    }
}
public class MyStrategyContext
{
    private readonly IMyStrategy _ImyStrategy;

    public MyStrategyContextIMyStrategy(IMyStrategy  myStragegy)
    {
        _ImyStrategy = myStragegy
    }

    public string GenerateResult(string someValue)
    {
        return _ImyStrategy .Generate(someValue);
    }
}

[Test]
    public void GenerateValue()
    {
   var abc = new MyStrategyContext(new StragegyA());
       abc.GenerateResult("hey print");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion